# Why can't I see the list of my page fans?

Tags: facebook-pages

Why can't I see the list of my page fans?

I have deleted 250 fans recently and there are still 400 fans; when I want to continue deleting them, Facebook shows me this message:

> No results found.

As in the screenshot below:

[image: No results found]

Comment: Could you post a link to the page? It would be helpful to see if the issue is whether or not the fans are there vs. whether or not they are visible.

Comment: @batpigandme this is the page : https://www.facebook.com/Aimad.Majdou

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for facebook users to have settings such that they 'ghost like' a page (and their names are not visible to a page admin) (see [Why can't I see everyone who has liked my page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=492316274139181) but this seems unlikely for all 400 people who have liked your page.

I'm not sure *why* the list isn't showing up for you- it might depend on how you go about retrieving the list of people who like your page.

The 'regular' way I use to see the people who like my facebook page is by using facebook as "Page name" and then clicking on the people icon in the upper left hand corner of the facebook toolbar:

[image]

This should give you a dropdown showing the last few people to have liked the page, and then you can expand it by clicking on *See All* at the bottom. (You can also switch between viewing 'people who like this' and 'pages who like this')

Alternately, you can get your facebook page ID by going to
`http://graph.facebook.com/*page_name*`
which will list page attributes the first of which is your page ID (in the case of your page the ID is 257047494357563)

As the admin if you go to
`https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=*page_ID*`
this should also take you to a list of the people who like your page.

Comment: okey, I tried the  regular way you used and it shows me only 5 persons, but when I click on see all No results found, so I need to display the full list to be able to delete some fans.

I also tried this : `https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=Aimad.Majdou` but it shows me `The server found your request confusing and isn't sure how to proceed.`

Comment: @SpoonYukina that's because the page_id= parameter you gave is incorrect (Aimad.Majdou is the page_name). Try `https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=257047494357563`

Comment: I still can't see the list of my fans

Answer (score 0):

One method that works for me:

- Go to your page, select "Settings"
- Select "Banned Users"
- Above the list of banner users, click the dropdown; it will offer "People who like this" and "Pages that like this".

The display initially only shows part of the list, but if you scroll to the bottom repeatedly, you will eventually have the full list.